# How to integrate legacy JavaScript with NodeJS in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, integration, legacy

Hypothetical legacy scenario:

Say I have 4 scripts that simply get concatenated together as a single script for deployment to provide a utility library with a global namespace in the browser.
I then have 1 separate application script that utilizes the library.
Something like:

```
<script src="library.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

In my app.js script, calls are made to the library methods through its namespace, like

```
var id = lib.id(prefix);
```

I see that 1 of the 4 library scripts is a useful utility that I want to turn into a Node module. I copy it and create a package and publish it to npm to use in new development.

Problem: Now I have two versions of this script to maintain - one for Node and one for the legacy library.

**Is there a way to have one common file that I can include in both the Node module and the legacy library? Or am I stuck maintaining two versions of the file until we phase out the legacy code?**

Additional info:

I looked at browserify and webpack, thinking they might be useful, but both suffer from a problem I don't know how to get around. Unless the end module defines global variables, I can't use the module in legacy code, as there is no require command available. In other words, I can't browserify a Node module, then drop it into a legacy web page and use it in my existing app.js, because I can't call `var mymodule = require('mymodule')`. Is there any way to get browserify or webpack to define and expose a require function to let me access my new Node module from a legacy codebase? Surely, this is not a unique scenario.

Comment: I don't use webpack, but using `jspm` or `rollup` you can build your script as UMD, so it can be used as global, AMD and Commonjs via feature detection.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a [UMD pattern](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) to ensure that the module can be used both as a global and in commonJS (ie- node) systems.

The pattern that would fit best for you is [returnExports](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/returnExports.js). This ensures that all exported properties are either applied to the global object (ie- window) or to the module object in node.

Since you are not using AMD, you can simplify the pattern somewhat and remove the first chunk of the if statements on lines 18 and 42.

This will require you to reorganize your code so that it fits in with the pattern.

There are other patterns that you may use, such as [commonJsStrictGlobal](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/commonjsStrictGlobal.js), but I personally prefer returnExports.

Comment: This doesn't appear to address my problem, so I need to work on stating my problem more clearly. Imagine I have 4 (legacy) scripts concatenated together into a single script. Say I take script #2 and copy it to another project, create a Node module out of it, and publish it via npm. Now I want to replace the #2 script in my legacy code with, effectively, a require call. Or are you saying I would somehow include the new script file from the node project, assuming I write it using a UMD pattern? If so, how to access it from the npm module?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that you can use *exactly* the same file in node (ie- as a commonJS module) as well as in a script tag (ie- in a global context). Presumably, you will publish the UMD variant of the file as an npm module. After you install it, you will most likely want to create a build step (using gulp, grunt, npm scripts or your favorite task runner) that will copy the desired UMD file into the proper place in your web app. Since you are using the UMD pattern, you will be able to access globals from your script #2 directly.

Comment: I see that you are saying that the scripts are concatenated, but your question above uses separate script tags. It doesn't really matter. If they are concatenated, you just need to make sure that you grab the proper file from the npm module for concatenation.

Comment: Sorry if the example was confusing - in the example, library.js is a concatenation of four scripts, and app.js is dependent on that library. But it's the library script I'm trying to assemble, which now shares a script with a NodeJS module. So I guess what I need to figure out is, how to include that script from a node module, which needs to be written using the UMD pattern. Correct?

Comment: Yes, but to do that is simple. Since you are using a UMD pattern, you can just concatenate as-is. That is the goal behind UMD. It can be used in different module contexts.